# Saitek Cyborg v7 keyboard muting with backspace button?

Tags: keyboard, mute

Whenever I hold backspace on my keyboard to delete a line of text, my computer mutes. Why? How do I stop this? MadCatz wants me to send my keyboard in to them for 'warranty service' when I know it's been out of warranty for a while, and I lost my reciept long ago. I have the newest drivers and programming software installed, and it's still doing it.

Comment: Have you tried it on a different computer? The keyboard could somehow be defective and sending the 'mute' keycode, in which case bringing it to another computer will show the same problem, or you could have some gummed up keyboard software installed on your PC.

Comment: I have tried it on another computer, also running windows 7. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted their cutomer support and he said :
Try the following;

1. Unplug your V7 from your computer.
2. Use a different Keyboard and begin to re install your driver from cyborggaming.com
3. the install WIZARD may ask you if it is ok to un-install or overwrite the previous driver, if it does please agree to it and click on "yes to all" if it ask to overwrite any files.
4. If the install WIZARD then ask to restart your computer then do so
5. Once new driver is INSTALLED plug in your keyboard and you should be set to go.

worked for me thank god i love this keyboard so much

Answer (score -1):

Honestly you should get a different keyboard. I currently have the cyborg v7 and just skimming through the programming I can tell it quite a mess.

MadCatz is the original company and cyborg is one of their sister companies. MadCatz is known for having cheap and low quality equipment that is just meant to meet a customers budget and they throw some fancy lighting or other aesthetics to make the product worth the buy.

They are also really into making console equipment and that's not great quality either. Great looks, low price, something you should avoid. Mechanical keyboards are not necessary. I would go with companies like Razer, Logitech, thermaltake, roccat, and even azio has some decent built keyboards.

If you want top of the line keyboards that you can trust I would go with Razer. I recommend the Razer black widow as it is affordable but is built to last and still has 6 programmable keys.